# How to Setup an Oracle JDBC Data Source on WebSphere Application Server 7 Step-by-Step

Tags: jdbc, websphere, datasource

How do you setup an Oracle JDBC data source on WebSphere Application Server 7 using Admin Console?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

1. Login to the Admin Console of the running server, i.e. Window ->
   Show Views -> Servers | right click the server -> Run Administration
   -> Run Administrative Console
2. Environment -> WebSphere variables
3. Find “**ORACLE JDBC DRIVER PATH**” Name out of the list (second page)
   and click its link
4. Set its “Value” to the “directory” (not the actual path + filename)
   where your ojdbc6.jar resides on your file system

   We can set this path externally, either a stand alone ojdbc6.jar or find it with Oracle client packages, i.e. C:\app\\product\11.2.0\client_1
5. Click “Apply”, then “Save” (on top)
6. Back to WAS Admin Console, go to Security -> Global security
7. On “Authentication” panel, expand “Java Authentication and
   Authorization Service” -> J2C authentication data
8. Click “New”
9. Give it an Alias name, i.e. Alias_Oracle and input our current
   databases’ credential: User ID = your_db_username, Password =
   your_db_password
10. Click “Apply”, then “Save”
11. Go to Resources -> JDBC -> JDBC providers
12. Make sure that the right Scope has been selected, i.e.
     Node=DOMAINHOSTNAMENode01 or something
13. Click “New” to create a new JDBC provider

    Step 1: Select “Oracle” from “Database type” menu | Provider type = Oracle JDBC Driver | Implementation type = Connection pool data source

    Leave the “Name” as default, i.e. “Oracle JDBC Driver”

    Step 2: if you have setup the ORACLE JDBC DRIVER PATH correctly, it should have the appropriate “Class path” to “ojdbc6.jar” already selected for you
    Step 3: Summary, click “Finish”
14. Go to Resources -> JDBC -> Data sources
15. Make sure the right Scope is selected , i.e.
     Node=DOMAINHOSTNAMENode01 or something
16. Click “New”

    Step 1: Data source name = “Oracle JDBC Driver” | JNDI name = “jdbc/OracleDS”

    Step 2: Select “Select an existing JDBC provider” = “Oracle JDBC Driver”

    Step 3: URL = “jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port:db_alias” | Data store helper class name = “Oracle11g data store helper”

    Step 4: Component-managed authentication alias = DOMAINHOSTNAMENode01/Alias_Oracle

    select “DefaultPrincipalMapping”

    Step 5: Summary, click “Finish”
17. Back on “Data sources” screen, select the newly created data source
     and “Test connection”. If it succeeds, you are done
18. You can retrieve the data source programmatically:

    Context initContext = new InitialContext(); 
    dataSource = (DataSource)initContext.lookup("jdbc/OracleDS");